# how to create a textfield in an alert box in android?

Tags: android, textfield

This is what I use to create a textfield:

```
    final EditText username_input = new EditText(this); // create an text input field
    username_input.setHint("Enter Username"); // put a hint in it
```

but this creates a textfield where capslock is enabled on default.

How do I create a textfield where caplocks isn't enabled on default?

Comment: try `username_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);`

Comment: it worked? can post it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
username_input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the [`setInputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) method of the `EditText` object with an appropriate combination of [InputType flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) -- `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` should be fine for you.